# no product after "build success" of a cocoa touch static library project

Tags: iphone, arm, i386

I have searched so many problem but there is no the same as me.
on Xcode 4.3.2（4.3.1）

I added several files to a new cocoa touch static library project and use **iPhone Simulator** to build it, then receive **build success**, but no .a file in products group (the .a file is red in the files list, left of Xcode)

When I change the "iPhone Simulator" to **IOS Device**, also receive **build success**, but now I can see .a file is not red and I can find in the product folder^

After I use **lipo -info** to check the .a file, it shows that it only supports arm7 architecture, thus confirms my first action(no product built in **Simulator**)^ so the .a file can't be used in my another project(i know it only can be used in simulator by supporting i386 architecture)

Answer (score 0):

Use the command line. Here is a simple script I built a while back, it will even lipo your binaries together for you!

```
#!/bin/bash
#build the device
echo building for ARM architecture
xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos4.3 "ARCHS=armv6 armv7" build > /dev/null
#build the simulator
echo building for the i386 architecture
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator4.3 "ARCHS=i386 x86_64" "VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64" build > /dev/null
#make the folder
mkdir "Fat Binary"
#lipo suck it together
echo lipo binaries together
lipo -output Fat\ Binary/libMyLib.a  -create build/Release-iphoneos/liblibMyLib.a build/Release-iphonesimulator/libMyLib.a
echo lipo binary saved at $./Fat Binary/libMyLib.a
echo coping headers
cp -R build/Release-iphoneos/usr "Fat Binary"
echo [COMPLETE]
```

Just replace occurrences of `libMyLib.a` with the name of your library.

Comment: the command line is really amazing……but only                  xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator4.3 "ARCHS=i386 x86_64" "VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64" build > /dev/null                                can be excuted normally                                                . after excute                                                             xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos4.3 "ARCHS=armv6 armv7" build > /dev/null       it tells me ** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
 Check dependencies, how to solve it?